# Computing the shortest path between opposite vertices in two adjacent triangles

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, geodesic

consider the following situation but in 3D space.

[image]

In 3D the situation above would be two triangles "folded". The question I have is what's the length of the shortest curve joining $v$ and $w$, I've tried to formalize the problem as follow

$$
l(\alpha) = \lVert x + \alpha(y - x) - v \rVert + \lVert x + \alpha(y - x) - w \rVert
$$

and I try minimizing the above by varying $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$.

Differentiating and setting the result equal to $0$ yields

$$
\frac{dl}{d\alpha} = \left(\frac{x + \alpha(y - x) - v}{\lVert x + \alpha(y - x) - v \rVert} + \frac{x + \alpha(y - x) - w}{\lVert x + \alpha(y - x) - w \rVert}\right)^T(y-x) = 0
$$

and I later solve for $\alpha$. The thing about the equation above is that I can't find a simple way to isolate $\alpha$, is there a simple way to define the problem? or maybe an easy way to solve what I've already set up in closed form? (I think what I want is the length of the geodesic joining $v$ and $w$).

Comment: What is the space in which to consider the geodesic?

Comment: @Cesareo What do you mean?

Comment: Is it a Riemann space? Is is Euclidean?  Is it concerning the space concerning both triangles alone?

Comment: I don't know the difference, but from what I just read I'd say Euclidean.

Comment: If it is euclidean then the minimum distance is $\lVert v-w\rVert _2$.

Comment: What you just wrote is not a distance...  And even if that would be correct that's clearly not what I want... From the function l I wrote in the question it is clear I'm talking about a curve lying on the two triangles.

Comment: It is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

You’re already most of the way to a solution. Distribute the dot product to get a sum of two terms, move one of them to the other side of equal sign, cross multiply to eliminate the denominators (we know they can’t be zero) and square to get a cubic equation in $\alpha$. If you’re lucky, it will factor nicely, but I don’t expect that to be the case.

---

There’s a fairly straightforward geometric construction that allows you to compute the length of this shortest path directly.

[image: Unfolded triangles]

Let $v'$ be the foot of the altitude from $v$ and $w'$ the foot of the altitude from $w$. These points are the orthogonal projections of $v$ and $w$, respectively, onto the line $xy$. Extend the segment $vv'$ toward $w$ to form the right triangle $\triangle{vqw}$. We then have by the Pythagorean theorem $$vw^2=vq^2+qw^2 = (vv'+ww')^2+(v'w')^2.$$ You can use the similarity of the three triangles in the diagram to compute $p$, should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the shortest curve which lies on the surface of the triangles, then you should just unfold them on the plane, draw the straight line from $v$ to $w$ and then fold back again.

Comment: So you would set an orthonormal reference frame on the vertex $v$, lying on the triangle $v,x,y$ rotate $w$ and compute the length of $v,w$, because such transformation is a local isometry then we will preserve the length of the geodesic. Is this correct? If yes, are there other ways to compute such length without unfolding?

Comment: I would not use a coordinate system for that, just simple trigonometry, since you can compute all side lengths and angles in advance.

Comment: Let me think this through...

Comment: Hi, is it correct say that the shortest path will be given by the length of the curve given by the intersection of the plane spanned by $v-p(\alpha)$ and $w-p(\alpha)$ with the two triangles? here $\alpha$ is chosen in such a way that the plane is orthogonal to $y - x$?

Comment: @user8469759 Even in your planar diagram above, that’s not true: No plane that includes the line through $v$ and $w$ is orthogonal to the common edge.